# Dealing with <html:options>

Tags: jsp-tags, html-select

When loading the dropdowns dynamically using `<html:options>` in JSP, how do I select an option by default?

Here is my code:

```
<html:select property="menu" >
    <html:option value="">–SELECT–</html:option>
    <html:options collection="menuList" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
</html:select>
```

Comment: You're using more than just JSP there.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the selected item like this:

```
<html:select property="selectedItem">
```

All you have to do in your Action is to call the setSelectedItem("myselection") from your Form object.

I Assume you use Struts here.